# AtomicInteger calculation in a loop

Tags: java, atomic

```
public final int getAndIncrement() {
for (;;) {
    int current = get();
    int next = current + 1;
    if (compareAndSet(current, next))
        return current;
   }
}
```

I found that the increment method works within a loop block. Why can't we just calculate a result without any looping? What is sence on it?

Comment: Think about what happens if somebody else changes the value at the same time, and remember that AtomicInteger does not use locking (at least if the platform has a CAS instruction)

Answer (score 6):

If another thread came along and changed the value of `AtomicInteger` between `int current = get()` and `compareAndSet(current, next)`, then the `compareAndSet` call would fail. Using a loop ensures that this possibility will never happen.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible for the call to `compareAndSet` to return false if another thread increments or otherwise modifies the `AtomicInteger` at the same time that the current thread is incrementing the `AtomicInteger`

1. current thread calls `current = get()`
2. another thread modifies the `AtomicInteger`
3. current thread calls `next = current + 1`
4. current thread calls `if(compareAndSet(current, next))`

On step 4, the call to `compareAndSet` will return false and will leave the `AtomicInteger` unchanged because `current` will not match the current value of the `AtomicInteger` (due to another thread having modified it on step 2); therefore the method loops and tries again

Answer (score 1):

compareAndSet might fail if another thread is updating. The for(;;) is a bit weird, I would have gone for while(true).

This is called optimistic locking.

Comment: ok , but is it posible a situation when the  **if (compareAndSet(current, next))** gives the true and before we return the result some other thrid finished changin value?

Comment: The return value may change indeed but the update is atomic, which is the main point here since it is done in a non blocking way. Given that it is by design non blocking, you cannot assume that the return value stays fixed for any amount of time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have three threads T1, T2, T3 running

```
T1: int current = get(); == 0
T2: int current = get(); == 0
T3: int current = get(); == 0
T3: int next = current + 1;
T1: int next = current + 1;
T2: int next = current + 1;
T2: if (compareAndSet(current, next)) // true
T2:     return current;
T3: if (compareAndSet(current, next)) // false
T1: if (compareAndSet(current, next)) // false
```

T1 and T3 need to try again, and only one might succeed the second time.